# Add key-value for Ruby Hash from within the Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key-value

What's the best way to add a key-value pair to an hash object, from within the hash object itself?

The common way I know to add a new key to a hash is as follows:

```
hash = Hash.new
hash[:key] = 'value'
hash[:key] # => 'value'
```

What if I wan't to create a new hash which already has this key after its creation?

```
hash = Hash.new
hash[:key] # => 'value'
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve? It's not very clear.

Comment: I don't know who it was but I have to say, people who downvote other people because a question isn't clear enough, shouldn't be on a site which is there to help people. If a question isn't clear enough it can be improved.

Comment: You want to create a **default value**.. See this [new(obj) → new_hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-new)

Comment: @ArupRakshit that looks like an answer, not just a comment, please repost that as an answer if this would solve the problem.

Comment: @NDM Someone did - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24034213/2767755) ..:-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit ok, couldnt see that from within the review page :)

Answer (score 1):

To create a Hash with an already initialized set of values you can do:

```
hash = { :key => 'value' }
hash[:key]    # ===> This evaluates to 'value'
```

Just remember, the idiomatic way to create an empty hash in Ruby is:

```
hash = {}
```

Not `hash = Hash.new` like you exemplified.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean set the default value? is so, you could do with:

```
hash = Hash.new('value')
hash[:key] # => 'value'
```

Comment: Yes.. That's what I meant. But it is a default value. Don't think, it is added to any key. When there will not be any key exist, then if you want to access the key, *default* value will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean i the other answers aren't what you want, you can create a hash with some keys and values allready filled like this

```
hash = {:key => 'value'} #{:key=>"value"}
```

and like the others said, the default value for key's not allready present is given by passing a block tot the hash at creation time like

```
hash = Hash.new('value') #{}
hash[:test] #"value"
```

or

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Go Fish: #{key}" } #{}
h[:test] #"Go Fish: test"
```

Thje last sample teken from http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html